# Protect fields accessed by several threads concurrently

Tags: c#, concurrency, synchronization

I have an example of class in which `GetEntity` and `Reconfigure` methods can be executed concurrently by several threads.

```cs
class Store
{
    private int number;
    private string name;
    private Rules rules;
    private Database database;

    public Entity GetEntity(int id)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"{number} {name}");
        return database.Get(rules, id);
    }

    public void Reconfigure(Config config)
    {
        number = config.Number;
        name = config.Name;
        policy = new Rules { Timeout = config.Timeout };
        database = DatabaseFactory.GetDatabase(config.DatabaseData);
    }
}
class Rules { }
class Database { }
```

- Do I actually need to synchronize read/assign operations to `number` / `name` / `rules` / `database` fields?
- If one thread is updating a pointer on object and the other one is reading the pointer in the same time, can the last one read corrupted data or face some other issues?

Comment: Add a lock object to make sure about that.

Comment: If `Reconfigure` can be called at anytime then yes, you need to use some synchronization primitive.

Comment: @peter, if I use Interlocked.Exchange(ref database,DatabaseFactory.GetDatabase(config.DatabaseData)), will I make my read operation in GetEntity method and assign operation in Reconfigure thread safe or only assign operation?

Comment: @tki This is just one side of the story. Inside your `GetEntity` you would need to call `Interlocked.CompareAndExchange(ref database, null, null);` to get the most recent version. If you are not familiar with synchronization primitives then please read these articles ([1](http://www.albahari.com/threading/part2.aspx#_Synchronization), [2](http://www.albahari.com/threading/part4.aspx#_Nonblocking_Synchronization)) at least.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, synchronization is needed in this case. Otherwise a read operation could see a torn/corrupted configuration, i.e. a mix of new and old configuration values. Also two concurrent write operations could result to a long-lasting corrupted configuration (until the next write operation).